# Find minimizer of mean values

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

i'd like to know if there is an analytical method to solve the following optimisation problem :
$\forall i=1,..,n$ find $\omega_i^{}$ and $\alpha_i^{}$ such that:

$\dfrac{1}{n} \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big(\omega_i^{} X_i - \alpha_i^{} Y_i \Big)= M$

where $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \omega_i^{}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i^{}=n$
and $X_i,Y_i \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $M\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Why do you think this is nonlinear optimisation?  The degree of the decision variables is one in each term.

Comment: Could you clarify what needs to be optimized? That is, what needs to maximized/minimized?

Comment: the aim is to find the weight $\omega_i$ and $\alpha_i$ that minimize the distance between the two means through an analytical method.